# Filtering a list by a bitarray

Tags: python, python-2.7, bitarray

```
import bitarray
from random import randint

LEN = 100

main_array = [randint(0, LEN) for _ in range(LEN)]
init_bit = bitarray.bitarray([True]*LEN)
false_points = [randint(0, LEN) for _ in range(30)]

print init_bit
for i in false_points: init_bit[i] = False
print init_bit
```

This prints:

```
bitarray('1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111')
[20, 31, 3, 97, 64, 96, 74, 83, 96, 56, 30, 9, 63, 50, 15, 65, 18, 97, 37, 11, 37, 25, 24, 36, 17, 85, 25, 32, 37, 1, 19, 24, 79, 20, 55, 66, 73, 13, 55, 69, 14, 21, 69, 66, 20, 99, 52, 68, 98, 97, 70, 42, 34, 28, 20, 90, 9, 61, 37, 44, 81, 26, 89, 20, 89, 54, 39, 19, 5, 87, 35, 92, 80, 13, 26, 16, 33, 38, 84, 98, 72, 15, 50, 43, 34, 58, 4, 9, 14, 28, 69, 69, 32, 36, 41, 98, 43, 99, 78, 80]
bitarray('0111110110001111111111110011111111111110111000101100011111100011111111111101110001101111011111111010')
```

I want to remove the values in the `main_array` where the corresponding bit is `False` or 0. i.e. there are 30 False bits in `init_bit` so the `main_array` should be filtered where the bit is 0 and become an array of 70 elements maintaining sequence.

I used this: `filter(lambda t: t[1] == True, zip(main_array, init_bit))` but this is going to take up a lot of memory if my bitarray is very long.

How can I do this in a faster way?

Comment: Have you thought of using `itertools.izip()` and `itertools.ifilter()` ?

Comment: `izip()` is working well and way faster than `zip`. So I guess this should be the answer. Among `izip()` and `ifilter()` which should be better for a very long array?

Comment: `itertools.ifilter(lambda t: t[1], itertools.izip(main_array, init_bit))` is also a good option.

Comment: Do you need the whole result in memory? Or can you work on the result iteratively?  That would help.

Comment: `main_array` would be there in the memory and `init_bit` will be used to filter that array. `initi_bit` is going to change frequently

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a `ifilter` with an extra lambda function you can simply use a list comprehension :

```
>>> from itertools import izip
>>> [i for i,j in izip(main_array, init_bit) if j]
```